# What should be the directory of an Image in Android

Tags: android, image, imageview

I have an image that has to be shown by imageview what should be the perfect directory for loading it as bitmap from string  .I have tried putting it resource folder but failed.It would be great if you provide folder hierarchy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resource images should be stored in a `res/drawable` variant according to [these guidelines](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html).

By variant I mean any density dependant (`-hdpi`, `-xhdpi`...), orientation dependant (`-land`, `-port`), or any other qualifier or combination defined in the *Table 2* of the linked document (mind the order of the qualifiers, it does matter as explained in the document).

It is a best practice to consider `/res/drawable` as a fallback should no better qualified directory apply.

Answer (score 1):

can you post your code? Typically I put my images in `drawable` folder. By displaying it in imageView you should get the `id` of the image you wanted to place.